# Concern with Multiple mixed repeated measure analysis/ Ancova

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, anova

I can't understand what type of graphical analysis is this in the attached figure.
[image]

The statistical analysis conducted was a MMRM or ANCOVA?  How can they combine control and treatment in one line (MMRM one)
[the picture is from `donanemab` study)

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The figure didn't come through.  Please try uploading again.

Comment: Apologize  for this, now it should be present. Many thanks

Comment: Hello! Please could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the following:

MMRM = Mixed Model for Repeated Measures, and

DPM = Disease Progression Model

> The statistical analysis conducted was a MMRM or ancova ?

It is a MMRM. There are presumably repeated measures within participants / subjects so a mixed model would be a fairly typical approach.

> How can they combine control and treatment in one line (the MMRM one) ?

I don't know what you mean by combine them "in one line" ? For example, the first MMRM point estimate in the figure, for `iADRS Score`, is approximately 20. Since this is greater than zero, it means that the treatment is protective.